# Setup existing Yii project on xampp linux

Tags: php, linux, yii, xampp

I need to edit an existing yii app but got no idea how to setup in xampp.

I downloaded everything from the server and moved the folders to /opt/lampp/htdocs

But then i got no idea how to get the application running.
When i try

```
/localhost/yiidirectory
```

It shows me the file structure so the app isn't executing.

Can you give me some advise to accelerate the problem solving ?

Answer (score 0):

Since windows 7 I believe you need to use:

```
http://127.0.0.1/yiidirectory
```

If that doesn't work then check your xampp setup:
http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/100/yii-and-xampp-server-on-windows/

The DNS resolver just hands back localhost so it never resolves it for the app/browser.